# How to insert a space between "file" and "git" + How to get full path to show?

Tags: command-line, git, zsh

1) How to insert a space in between the `current directory` (`file`) and the `git_prompt_info` (`git`) without ending up with an extra space between the `current directory` and the `text cursor` ?

When no space is added :

```
➜ user ~ |
➜ user ~ cd file|     
➜ user filegit:(master) ✗ |
```

Note : `|` represents the text cursor.

The source (.zshrc):

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ %{$fg_bold[red]%}$USER %{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%c%{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'
```

When a space is added :

```
➜ user ~  |     
➜ user ~  cd file|     
➜ user file git:(master) ✗ |
```

Note : The space between the `current directory` (`~`) and the `git_prompt_info` (`git`) may have been added, but an extra space was added between the `current directory` (`~`) and the `text cursor` (`|`).

The source (.zshrc):

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ %{$fg_bold[red]%}$USER %{$fg_bold[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'
```

Note : The only change made, is a space that was added here `%c%` -> `%c %`.

2) And from there, how do I get the full path to show ?

```
➜ user ~ cd file|    
➜ user ~/file git:(master) ✗ |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `git_prompt_info` function you should prefix the output with a space if there is any output, otherwise not. (As a side note: you probably want to look into the vcs_info system that is integrated into zsh, see the zshcontrib manual page)

As to your second question: If I understand you correctly you should be able to use `%~` instead of `%c` to get what you want. If you really want the *full* path to be shown use `%d`. Have a look at the [`zshmisc` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zshmisc.1.html) ([prompt expansion section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion)) for more variations of this.